# Why is a java enum not constructing till after a class callback is hit?

Tags: java, android, enums, construction

I have an Android class which has a callback from an asynchronous HTTP process, and an enum with a number of status codes in:

```
public abstract class HttpPackage {

    public enum StatusCode {
        SUCCESS(0),
        NOT_FOUND(100),
        USERNAME_NOT_FOUND(101),
        AUTH_FAILED(110),
        SAVE_ERROR(111)
        //etc.

        private final int mCode;

        StatusCode(int i) {
            mCode = i;
            sByCode.put(i, this);
        }

    }

    private static final HashMap<Integer, StatusCode> sByCode = new HashMap<Integer, StatusCode>();

    //...
}
```

I've discovered the callback in the HttpPackage class is being hit before the `enum` constructs, which means that when I try to extract a status code from the static code map, it returns null, and my code thinks all the feeds are failing (when they aren't).  Why would this `enum` be constructing after the callback is hit?

Comment: Why would you bother having an external map of status codes when you already have an enum of status codes? Why not keep it in the enum?

Comment: It wouldn't compile.  I've just discovered that removing the `static` modifier helps, but this leaves me with no static way to *access* the map.

Comment: You access it through the enum.

Comment: No **static** way.  See below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes are loaded lazily in Java. If you access the map before the StatusCode class is loaded, then of course it will be empty.

The map should be in the enum itself. This way, if you're accessing the map, you're guaranteed that the enum class has been loaded, and that the map is not empty. The map should also be hidden from the outside code. You should provide a static `StatusCode getByCode(int code)` method in the enum.

EDIT: example code:

```
public enum StatusCode {
    SUCCESS(0),
    NOT_FOUND(100),
    USERNAME_NOT_FOUND(101),
    AUTH_FAILED(110),
    SAVE_ERROR(111);

    private final int code;

    private static final Map<Integer, StatusCode> map = new HashMap<Integer, StatusCode>();

    static {
        for (StatusCode sc : values()) {
            map.put(sc.getCode(), sc);
        }
    }

    StatusCode(int i) {
        this.code = i;
    }

    public static StatusCode getByCode(int code) {
        return map.get(code);
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(StatusCode.getByCode(111));
    }
}
```

Or you could also use a `getMap()` static method inside the constructor which lazily initializes the map if it's null.

Comment: Also, recall that generic type parameters are erased at compile time, so there's no run-time reference from sByCode to the StatusCode class that would cause the class to be loaded when the map is accessed.

Comment: If I make `sByCode` static it won't initialize in the `enum` constructor and if I don't make it static the `getByCode` method can't see it.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I've solved this using a simple "iterate through the `values()` and check for equality, returning a match" method, but it seems a shame not to be able to use `HashMap`.

Comment: @AndrewWyld the typical way I've seen that worked around is to make sByCode a static member of the enum class, and then in a static initializer block populate it with the enum values.

Comment: Ah, static initializer.  Hadn't thought of that.  Thanks!